# While deploying contract i got Warning: Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes

Tags: solidity, optimization, uniswapv2

I'm trying to deploy UniswapV2Router02 but i got error Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes.

How do I proceed with optimization?

Now i'm using remix and
current compiler is 0.6.6

```
pragma solidity =0.6.6;

import '@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol';
import '@uniswap/lib/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';

import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
import './libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol';
import './libraries/SafeMath.sol';
import './interfaces/IERC20.sol';
import './interfaces/IWETH.sol';

contract UniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router02 {
// code is here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decrease the size of your contracts as at max we can only deploy 24kb of code.
Remove safeMath as it's not neccessary in newer versions of solidity.
Also check for any code that isn't usefull.

Comment: So only way to fix is removing the code?

Comment: Yeah as long as it's more than 24kb you can't deploy.
If you want to learn more check this :- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/

Comment: I solve this problem with "Enable optimization" in remix
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/155378/while-deploying-contract-i-got-warning-contract-code-size-exceeds-24576-bytes